# Finding a bijection from a set of matrices to $\mathbb R^3$ $\setminus{(0,0,0)}$

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory

> Let $G$ denote the group of all $3 \times 3$ invertible square matrices with real entries under multiplication. Let $N$ denote the subset of matrices in $G$ with first column $\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$. Give a surjective map from $G$ to $\mathbb R^3$ $\setminus{(0,0,0)}$  such that the inverse image of any point is bijective to $N$.

My attempt :

The elements of the set $N$ look like $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & x_1 & x_2\\ 0 & y_1 & y_2 \\ 0 & z_1 & z_2 \end{array}\right)$. Am I supposed to find a bijective map from $N$ to $\mathbb R^3$ $\setminus{(0,0,0)}$ ??

If so, then we have to find a bijection between  $\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^3$ $\setminus{(0,0,0)}$ since any $3 \times 3$ matrix can be written as an element of $\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3$. Again, the first column is fixed and hence it is reduced to $\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3$. But here I'm facing trouble to find such bijection.

Thanks in advance !!

P.S. The question is quite opaque to me.

Comment: No, your "if so" doesn't follow. Because the matrices are invertible

Comment: "a surjective map from $G$ to $\mathbb R^3$ $\setminus{(0,0,0)}$  such that the inverse image of any point is bijective to $N$" is not a bijection between $N$ and $\Bbb R^3\setminus (0,0,0)$.

Comment: @Arthur then what is it ??

Comment: It's a map from $G$ to $\Bbb R^3/(0,0,0)$. It's surjective. And if you take an arbitrary $v\in \Bbb R^3/(0,0,0)$ and look at _all_ the invertible matrices that are sent to that $v$, that collection of matrices will looks a lot like $N$. That's the kind of function they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map from that send a matrix whose first column is $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$ to the point $(x,y,z)$ is a surjection from $G$ to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus (0,0,0)$. The inverse image of the point $(x,y,z)$ is the set of all invertible matrices whose first column is $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$.

To establish a bijection between invertible matrices with first column $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and invertible matrices with first column $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$, simply divide the first row of a matrix by $x$, then subtract $y$ times the first row from the second row, then subtract $z$ times the first row from the third row. Each of these operations leaves the matrix invertible (think of Gaussian Elimination) and there is a unique way to reverse them.

EDIT: if $x=0$ then the rows need to be swapped around first, so that all the rows get divided by either $y$ or $z$ instead.